# How to display items using sessions

Tags: php, session

I am doing a opencourse project where I have to load a menu through a xml file and keep track of what the user buys and display it in a cart. Almost everything is done but I dont seem to access the items bought through the `$_SESSIONS`. The idea of how the web is running is simple it loads a particular category from the menu using a get variable and when an item is bought I am saving it in the $_SESSION as an array but when I visit `cart.php` I dont seem to see the record in `$_SESSION`

here is my index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

//loading the xml file
$dom = simplexml_load_file("../menu.xml");

// variable to store category id
$categoryid;

//to store all the data of a particular category id
$names = [];

//to store the name of the category
$categoryname;

//to count how many categories were in there in the xml file
$categorycount = count($dom->xpath("/menu/category"));

//Checking if the user visited via GET and if GET variable is set
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
{

    if(!isset($_GET["cat"]))
    {
        $categoryid = 1;
    }
    // checking if the variable is set within the limits of number of categories loaded
    else if (isset($_GET["cat"]) && ($_GET["cat"] > 0 && $_GET["cat"] <= $categorycount))
    {
        $categoryid = $_GET["cat"];
    }
    else
    {
        print("invalid category id");
    }

    //now loading the appropriate category from xml
    foreach($dom->xpath("/menu/category[@id = '{$categoryid}']") as $category)
    {
        $categoryname = $category->option;

        //saving the data
        foreach($category->name as $name)
        {
            $names[] = [
                    "optionname" => $name->type,
                    "small" => $name->small,
                    "large" => $name->large,
                    "general" => $name->general
                    ];
        }   
    }

    //loading the displaying files
    include("../views/header.php");
    include("../views/viewpage.php");

}
```

?>

the file `header.php` just got the `head` tag of the file so not pasting it here, table is produced by `viewpage.php` so its code is as follows

```
<body>
<div class = "cart">
    <a href= "cart.php">View Cart</a>
</div>
<?php if(isset($error)): ?>
<div class = "warning">
    <p>No Item was selected</p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan = "4"><?= $categoryname ?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Options</th>
                <th>Small</th>
                <th>Large</th>
                <th>General Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <form action = "buy.php" method = "POST">
                <?php foreach($names as $item): ?>
                <tr class = "even">
                    <td><?= $item["optionname"] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- checking every key value pair of $item if its empty and dynamically giving the names to inputs combining name and price-->
                        <?php if($item["small"] != ""): ?>
                        <?= $item["small"] ?>
                        <input type = "text" name = "<?= $item["optionname"]?>#<?=$item["small"]?>">
                        </input>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($item["large"] != ""): ?>
                        <?= $item["large"] ?>
                        <input type = "text" name = "<?= $item["optionname"]?>#<?= $item["large"] ?>">
                        </input>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($item["general"] != ""): ?>
                        <?= $item["general"] ?> 
                        <input type = "text" name = "<?= $item["optionname"]?>#<?= $item["general"] ?>">
                        </input>    
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>

        <input type = "submit" value = "Buy!">
    </form>

    <!-- printing the list to display categories using the categorycount variable-->
    <div class= "list">
        <h4>category</h4>
        <?php
            for($i = 1; $i <= $categorycount; $i++)
            {
                print("<ul>
                        <li><a href = \"?cat={$i}\">{$i}</a></li>
                      </ul>");
            }   
        ?>
    </div>  
</body>
```

the buying process is done by `buy.php`, its code is as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
//print_r($_POST);
//print("</br>");

$quantity;
$typename;
$price;
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    //array to save category name, its size, price and quantity of each item
    $cart = [];

    if(!empty($value))
    {
        $quantity = $value;
        //print($key ." val ". $value);
        //print("</br>");
        //breaking the input name to get the type thats in xml from input name, the section before '#' 
        $typename = strstr($key, "#", true);

        //getting the part that comes after '#'
        $price = substr($key, strpos($key, "#") + 1);

        //now converting the '_' to a space and '.'
        $typename = str_replace("_", " ", $typename);
        $price = str_replace("_", ".", $price);

        //checking if '&' in name is present then convert if to &amp;
        /*if(strpos($typename, "&"))
        {
            $typename = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $typename);
        }*/ 

        //print($typename);
        //print("</br>");
        //print($price);
        //print("</br>");

        //opening the xml file to search
        $dom = simplexml_load_file("../menu.xml");

        //searching
        foreach($dom->xpath("/menu/category") as $category)
        {
            //iterating over every name tag in xml
            foreach($category->name as $name)
            {
                //print("</br>checking on run{$name->type} </br></br>");
                //checking every type tag
                if($name->type == $typename)
                {
                    //storing what category name the type belongs to
                    $cartcategoryname = $category->option;
                    //print("the category is {$cartcategoryname}</br>");

                    //test to see what size the above matched type is
                    if($name->small == $price)
                    {
                        $size = "small";
                    }
                    else if($name->large == $price)
                    {
                        $size = "large";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $size = "general";
                    }
                }

            }

            /*adding the name,size,type quantity in an array
             * which would be added to $_SESSION and the array
             * would be wiped clean.*/ 
            $cart = [
                "category" => $cartcategoryname,
                "type" => $typename,
                "size" => $size,
                "price" => $price,
                "quantity" => $quantity
                ];  
        }   

        $_SESSION["cart"][] = $cart;
    }

    /* name of category, its type, size, price and quantity in 
     * arry cart */
    /*$cart[] = [
            "category" => $cartcategoryname,
            "type" => $typename,
            "size" => $size,
            "price" => $price,
            "quantity" => $quantity
            ];*/


    //print_r($cart);
    //print("</br></br></br>");

    //pushing the above created arror into session global
    //$_SESSION["cart"][] = $cart;      
}
//print_r($_SESSION);
//print("</br>");

/*foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $cartitem)
{
    print($cartitem["category"]."</br>");
    print($cartitem["quantity"]."</br>");
    print($cartitem["type"]."</br>");
}*/ 



$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'index.php?cat=1';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;

//header("Location: index.php?cat=1");
//exit;
```

?>

now when I use `print_r($_SESSION)` in `cart.php` I cant see any of the things
code for it is

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $cartitem)
{
    print($cartitem["category"]."</br>");
    print($cartitem["quantity"]."</br>");
    print($cartitem["type"]."</br>");
}
//phpinfo();
```

?>

the xml file is as follows

```
<menu>
<category id = '1'>
    <option>Pizzas</option> 
    <name>
        <type>Tomato &amp; Cheese</type>
        <small>5.50</small>
        <large>9.75</large>
        <general/>
    </name>
    <name>
        <type>Onions</type>
        <small>6.85</small>
        <large>10.85</large>
        <general/>
    </name>
</category>
<category id = '2'>
    <option>Side Orders</option> 
    <name>
        <type>Onion Rings</type>
        <small>2.60</small>
        <large>2.95</large>
        <general/>
    </name>
    <name>
        <type>French Fries</type>
        <small>2.85</small>
        <large>3.85</large>
        <general/>
    </name>
</category>
```

Comment: Did you `session_start()` on all the pages using session?

Comment: buy.php doesn't start a session, therefore, you won't be able to use $_SESSION["cart"], same with cart.php

Comment: including it also also dosent solve the problem

Comment: try to start all pages with <?php session_start(); error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); then print_r($_SESSION); wherever you use it, same for $_POST if needed, and let us know what errors occured if any EDIT: btw, I'll have pizza + french fries please ^^

Comment: adding <?php session_start(); error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); on every page and than print_r($_SESSION) is showing an empty array

Comment: seems that buy.php brings some trouble... I see you check the values a lot all the way through the process on that page, when you uncomment the line, any result shown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got the `$_SESSION` working in `cart.php`, by including `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1)`
I got an error `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active file] on line 0`
did a bit of google search and found out that xml data is still a xml data and one needs to `type cast` it into a `string`. Doing that allowed me to see the session variables in `cart.php`

Comment: nope still a lot of work to do but for now solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The :

`$_SESSION["cart"][] = $cart;` in `buy.php` is not inside the (correct) `foreach`.

Put it at the end but inside of

`foreach($dom->xpath("/menu/category[@id = '{$categoryid}']") as $category)` loop.

```
$cart = [
                "category" => $cartcategoryname,
                "type" => $typename,
                "size" => $size,
                "price" => $price,
                "quantity" => $quantity
                ];  

$_SESSION["cart"][] = $cart;
} // End of foreach($dom->xpath("/menu/category[@id = '{$categoryid}']") as $category)
```

Comment: one } too early you mean ?

Comment: putting $_SESSION["cart"][] = $cart; at the end but inside the foreach loop is also not helping, again getting an empty array in cart.php.... I think the older position too was correct I had checked its oput put, it was fine in buy.php, its cart.php which when clicked doesnt show any session variables